# QGIS Custom Python Function to Return Current Extent QGIS 2.18LTR

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, extents, virtual-layer

Related Question [Charts and Graphs that only display features in current extent](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302050/charts-and-graphs-that-only-display-features-in-current-extent)
Trying to write a custom function to return the current view extent. The below code is what I wrote based on the QGIS Cookbook https://docs.qgis.org/testing/pdf/en/QGIS-testing-PyQGISDeveloperCookbook-en.pdf. The return from the Output Preview is
`<built-in method xMinimum of QgsRectangle object at 0x000000...`
Any suggestions on where I am going wrong?

Function Code:

```
import math
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction, QMainWindow
canvas=QgsMapCanvas()
e=canvas.extent()
@qgsfunction(args=0, group='Custom', usesgeometry=True)
def CurrentExtent(value1, feature, parent):
    return str(e.xMinimum)+" "+str(e.yMaximum)+", "+str(e.xMaximum)+" "+str(e.yMaximum)+", "+str(e.xMaximum)+" "+str(e.yMinimum)+","+str(e.xMinimum)+" "+str(e.yMinimum)+"))"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You are calling the [QgsMapCanvas](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html) class instead of calling the **current** map canvas. So replace:

  ```
  canvas=QgsMapCanvas()
  ```

  with

  ```
  canvas=iface.mapCanvas()
  ```

  You will also need to add the following import line:

  ```
  from qgis.utils import iface
  ```

---

- When calling the extent funtions (i.e. `e.xMaximum`), you need to add parenthesis at the end (e.g. `e.xMaximum()`).

---

So your code could look like:

```
import math
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction, QMainWindow
canvas=iface.mapCanvas()
e=canvas.extent()
@qgsfunction(args=0, group='Custom', usesgeometry=True)
def CurrentExtent(value1, feature, parent):
    return str(e.xMinimum())+" "+str(e.yMaximum())+", "+str(e.xMaximum())+" "+str(e.yMaximum())+", "+str(e.xMaximum())+" "+str(e.yMinimum())+","+str(e.xMinimum())+" "+str(e.yMinimum())+"))"
```

[image]

Comment: @TylerVeinot - Most welcome, glad it worked :)

Comment: Side question: After making the function and considered it working, I went ahead and made a filter expression using the new function. It seems to only return the extent as it was when I written the filter, it will not recalculate the extent as I pan around. In order to update the extent value I have to go in and delete CurrentExtent() and rewrite it in order to update. Actually if I just delete the ) in "()" and retype it it will also return the new current extent.